# What would be the cheapest public transportation deal for me in Hong Kong?

Tags: budget, public-transport, tickets, airport-transfer, hong-kong

I'll visit HKG for two periods:

1. one evening, a day and a half
2. 3 days and a half

I wandered the net and saw some public transportation deals. 
But I'm confused which one would be the most economic for my needs
(is the daily ticket really economic? what would you recommend for me?)

- [HGK AirportExpress](https://www.paydollar.com/b2c2/AELControlServlet?action=aelshop&lang=eng&catid=10030)
- [Unlimited daily ticket](https://www.paydollar.com/b2c2/AELControlServlet?action=aelshop&lang=eng&catid=10422)
- [Airport express + 3 unlimited days](https://www.paydollar.com/b2c2/AELControlServlet?action=aelshop&lang=eng)
- [bus](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/bus_from_hkia.html)

I want to ask:

1. if I buy tickets online, how can i pick them up?
2. Do I get an octopus  ticket for which I can get refund at the end of use?
3. I cannot find the MTR and airport express fee from the airport to Hong Kong station
4. I couldn't understand if the unlimited tickets include all buses, tram and other discounts in stores like the octopus offers?

Comment: 3: http://www.mtr.com.hk/eng/fares_tickets/tf_index.html Only the Airport Express goes to the airport; the other possibilities are [bus](http://www.mtr.com.hk/eng/fares_tickets/bus_rf_index.html) + [MTR](http://www.mtr.com.hk/eng/fares_tickets/train_service_index.html) via Tung Chung or bus all the way. You'll find more information about other fares on the MTR site as well.

Comment: don't take taxis, they charge by area, so if you change area double the price, and its very easy to run up a big fare.

Comment: The [Airbus](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/bus_from_hkia.html) (A* numbers) is quite a bit cheaper than the airport express and can be more convenient if you have a bit of time to spare. There are a number of bus routes that probably pass close to where you need to go. You can use the Octopus stored-value card. If your first time in HK, be sure to take the Star Ferry across the harbour at least once .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is round-trip bus ticket (A11), which costs 65 HK dollars.

Answer (score 1):

Cheapest way to go Airport: MTR to Tung Chung Station. And take bus(S1) to Airport.

Centre to Tung Chung Station ($21.9 HKD octopus)
Tung Chung Station to Airport($3.5 HKD)
Total: $25.4 HKD